# Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Values - does it allocate new memory and time complexity

Tags: c#, dictionary, memory, time-complexity

I am new to C# and I want to understand what is the memory and time overhead of using `Dictionary.Values` property. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.values?view=netframework-4.7.2) I could find nothing about the algorithm time complexity specifications or about memory complexity? Am I looking at wrong place or is it undefined in C# spec?

P.S. I am coming from C++ bg.

Comment: The .NET Framework libraries are open source so you can [read it here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs#L157-L163) or [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,157).

Answer (score 11):

> is it undefined in C# spec?

It isn't defined in the C# spec because this isn't a C# feature - it is a framework implementation detail.

`.Values` is lazily instantiated *once* the first time it is requested; after that, the existing value is handed out. So yes, *some* memory might be allocated when it is first used. However, it doesn't contain a snapshot copy of the values, so : this isn't an 
expensive allocation. It simply contains a reference back to the parent dictionary instance.

```
private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary;
```

is literally the only field in `ValueCollection<TKey, TValue>`. It is essentially a facade that provides a value-centric view over the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding time complexity: Dictionary is pretty much equivalent to a hashmap. So reading an item can be expected to be O(1).
For inserting an item, it depends on the situation (because of possible memory allocation). It is either O(1) or O(n).